# how to close stdout for program from shell?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, file-descriptors

I mean not to redirect stdout to /dev/null, but block stdout before starting my program, so for example all of my `write(1, "dd", 2);` will return -1 as if stdout doesn't exists in my device.

Comment: I do not think you can do this, every process in Linux/UNIX when start open handlers 0,1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close a file descriptor with a redirection like `>&-` for stdout, or `9>&-` for fd 9. E.g.:

```
$ /bin/echo foo >&-
/bin/echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Note that the [standard says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> If file descriptor 0, 1, or 2 would otherwise be closed after a successful call to one of the exec family of functions, implementations may open an unspecified file for the file descriptor in the new process image.

so it might not stay closed in all systems. I did get the bad fd error on Linux and Mac, though.

Of course, many programs are likely made so that they expect that fds 0, 1 and 2 refer to open files, and they might misbehave if that's not the case. Commonly, this would happen when a newly-opened file would be put to one of those (as the system call uses the lowest free fd) and used accidentally by something unrelated.